# Android SDK acceptable file names

Tags: android, sdk, filenames

I am trying to run an app; however, it gives me the error:

> jonathan.JPG: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Is it that because of the extension? Does `.JPG` have to be lowercase?

Answer (score 2):

> is it that the extension, .JPG, has to be lowercase? .

Yes. Every character in the filename, including the extension, has to be either a lowercase English letter (`a` through `z`), a digit (`0` to `9`), a period (`.`), or an underscore (`_`).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the extension is part of the filename. Your exact issue was raised as an issue in the Android Open Source project issue tracker.

For resources Android only allows lowercase letters (a to z), digits (0-9), periods (.) and underscores (-)

Also if this a resource it's recommended to use PNGs instead of JPGs.